# How can I create a new object by input of dimensions?

Tags: dimensions

I have watched video tutorials how to create a simple rectangular object from a cube and in each it displays DIMENSIONS (x,y,z) in the object properties below Location, Rotation and Scale yet when I copy what I see in those videos I do NOT get Dimensions displayed. I have searched everywhere, even in Help, but cannot find how to display Dimensions to allow me to input the dimensions. I have found that I can create my object to the correct dimensions using SCALE but is that the correct method and why can't I get the Dimensions input box displayed? So frustrating that I can't even duplicate what I see in video tutorials. I have Blender version 2.29 as well as 2.83.

Comment: If you mean the Transform menu with Locacion, Rotation, Scale and Dimension, it's only available in Object Mode (Ctrl + Tab > Object Mode) by selecting the object and pressing N on the keyboard. If that's not the case, you could add the link to one of the videos and tell us the exact moment you saw the "Dimensions" part.

Comment: Thanks   Yes I meant the Transform menu.  I now can display "dimensions" after object selection and pressing N (in object mode which I was already in). I still cannot find any documentation on that. I can't find the video I saw it but did download the video and I can attach a still from that video if I new how to attach/insert an image   Thanks again.

Comment: Hi :). As @Emir said, you can't enter specific x,y,z dimensions when adding an object. You can easily do it later, using the Transform menu *(Sidebar (N) > Item tab > Dimensions)*

Comment: you can just edit your question and then drag and drop the image in there. That's all.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I see now there are TWO Transform menus the one which appears either all or most of the time on the right of screen (WITHOUT Dimensions) and the one which appears EITHER on selecting the object and pressing the N key OR 'grabbing' the < symbol across to the left. Learning by trying things and from you guys.   I firstly ADD an object and then select it, I didn't expect to enter dimensions during add.  Thanks again

Comment: Another question  How do you 'undo' something you did which wasn't a change to the object eg clicking on 'preset viewpoint' which changes the view which I have experimented with but then could get back to the view before I did that.

Comment: Hi :). Viewport view isn't stored in undo history. You always need to select a view manually to go back to it (top/front/side/etc...)